# Japanese characters in java webapp and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, unicode

I want to write a simple java web app that takes japanese characters and stores in db.(Oracle). My server is tomcat.

What are the things I need to ensure, rather what all places my encoding should be set correctly? I have UTF-8 in my IDE, and probably database config is also set to UTF-8. Would that be enough?

Does my server config needs to be modified to support transmission of Japanese characters?

Any pointers to sample application will be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check the DB charset with

```
SELECT *
  FROM SYS.v_$nls_parameters
```

and check that NLS_CHARACTERSET supports Japanesse (for example and not limited to: AL32UTF8, AL16UTF16)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a good encoding choice, but not the only one.

You should be aware if you're using Microsoft products that they [don't support UTF-8 natively](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580).  They have their own "standard" encoding called UCS-2.  You say Java and Oracle, so perhaps the warning isn't needed, but I didn't know if you have IIS as your web server, so I thought I'd point it out.

You also have to have the Japanese character sets installed on your machine: Kanji, Katakana, and the older Kaiji sets as well.

If you intend to actually type characters in Japanese, you'll need the Japanese IME installed.  [Here's](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/62/t1033147-typing-japanese-characters/) how to do it.